# when call yandex api It gives me 403 Forbidden by retrofit

Tags: retrofit, yandex-api

When I call this link 
https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=trnsl.1.1.20151201T195234Z.a35326958c23a7a8.51da9f9c1ffe2d901f1ee0e4bf3cfdadfe19b3f8&ui=ru&text=apple&lang=en-ru on my browser it works, but when I call it using retrofit It gives me 403 Forbidden. Вut that I  get only when I do not use the key in retrofit. When I use key, I get no callback  by debug. Please help, I am suffering for the second week

I use  retorfit  so :
API

```
     public interface APIService {

    @GET("translate")
    Call<Repo> loadRepo(
            @Query(value = "key", encoded = true) String key ,
                        @Query("ui") String ui,
                        @Query("text") String text,
                        @Query("lang") String lang1) };
Repo r; 
String text="apple"; String ui="ru"; 
String key="trnsl.1.1.20151201T195234Z.a35326958c23a7a8.51da9f9c1ffe2d901f1ee0e4bf3cfdadfe19b3f8"; 
String lang1="en-ru";


            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/")

                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    //                .client(httpClient)
                    .build();

            service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);


        service.loadRepo( URLEncoder.encode(key), ui, text, lang1).enqueue(new Callback<Repo>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<Repo> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

                r = response.body();
                int a = 1; // under debug here I look response and see 403 Forbidden

            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {


            }
        });
```

Comment: class Repo {
     String code;
     String lang;
     String text;
}

Comment: I added a full project with two class test, and test1. The difference in one variable key. In one case- the error 403,  in other cases there are no callback .   https://www.dropbox.com/s/61xgx0j6ql5o5c3/retro.rar?dl=0